# Parsing YouTube Json for Windows Store apps

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, windows-runtime, youtube-api, windows-store-apps

I generate C# Class from http://json2csharp.com/ for any YouTube URL, in which some names are invalid like as follows:

```
public class Feed
{
    public string __invalid_name__xmlns$media { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__gd$etag { get; set; }
}
```

In the above code actual Youtube name is `xmlns$media`, `gd$etag` like that...
when I change those to:

```
public class Feed
{
    public string xmlns$media { get; set; }
    public string gd$etag { get; set; }
}
```

in C# it shows error because of special character $, If I don't use $ parsing doesn't happens and returns Null.

Help me fixing this!

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
[DataContract]
public class Feed
{
    [DataMember(Name="xmlns$media")]
    public string xmlns_media { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="gd$etag")]
    public string gd_etag { get; set; }
}
```